# Key and value in Json

Tags: c#, json, paypal

This is how I work right now to build up membership on the website via paypal.

I would like to get done like that here:

```
   "plan": {
        "id": "P-rtfhfedh",
        "state": "ACTIVE",
        "name": "T-Shirt of the Month Club Plan",
        "description": "Template creation.",
        "type": "FIXED",
        "payment_definitions": [
          {
            "id": "PD-50606817NF8063316RWBZEUA",
            "name": "Regular Payments",
            "type": "REGULAR",
            "frequency": "Month",
            "amount": {
              "currency": "USD",
              "value": "100"
            }
          }
        ]
```

What I have done than to now in my MVC site it is like this:

```
int orderid = Convert.ToInt32(HelperClass.Helper.Settings.NyTal(8));

        JsonPaypal jsonpaypal = new JsonPaypal();
        jsonpaypal.IdValue = id + orderid;
        jsonpaypal.Name = "Medlemskab";
        jsonpaypal.description = "Medlemskab - Orderid: " + orderid;
        jsonpaypal.start_date = DateTime.Now;
        jsonpaypal.Plan = new string[] {
            "id:" Convert.ToString(id + orderid),
            "State": "ACTIVE",

        };
```

Class to JsonPaypal

```
public class JsonPaypal
{
    public int IdValue
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string description
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public DateTime start_date
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string payerURL
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Plan
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string URL
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string Obj
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I go into my plan and make multiple object which will also be shown from the code paypal made.

**The fault lies as said by Plan.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0S15.png)

Comment: "id:" Convert.ToString(id + orderid) ->  "id": Convert.ToString(id + orderid)

Comment: It gives me still red bugs and writes "Syntax error, '' Expected". It make it when I care about, and convert. @DmitriyZapevalov

Comment: It was just from first glance. At second glance: JsonPaypal.Plan is string and you are trying to assign `array` of string. Also `array` initialization values are splited with `;` there must not be `:`. I recomend you to create subclass JsonPaypal.Plan and with all fields and fill it.

Comment: @DmitriyZapevalov so you want a class action against the class I've created?

Comment: I suggest to represent whole `JSON` class hierarchy. So the `field` of top-level `JsonPaypal` whould by not simply string but instance of neasted class JsonPaypal.Plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `public string Plan { get; set; }` object to be a `string[]` string array.

Like this: `public string[] Plan { get; set; }`

This is why you are getting this red squiggly, as your code is trying to set a normal `string` to an array of `string`s.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT** Also, after more looking, I realised you are trying to add strings to your string array incorrectly.

Syntax for adding strings is like this:

```
string[] array = new string[] { "string 1", "string 2" };
```

Where you are creating your strings, and using other properties/variables to create them, ensure you are creating the string itself correctly. Close off your string and add `+` to append strings from methods or properties. Likewise, to add to a string from a method or property, add `+ " extra string stuff"`.

Like this

```
string[] array = new string[] {
                      "id: " + YourClass.Id,
                      "another string: " + myLocalVariable,  
                      "yet another " + AClass.Property + " class" };
```

**Your code where setting `jsonpaypal.Plan` should be...**

```
jsonpaypal.Plan = new string[] {
                       "id: " + Convert.ToString(id + orderid),
                       "State: ACTIVE" };
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've just re-looked at your code and edited my answer above. It will help, trust me. It was also failing before, because you had malformed strings to make up your `string[]`. Have a look; I've included some examples.

Comment: Your code `{ "id:" Convert.ToString(id + orderid), "State": "ACTIVE", }` is wrong. It must be written like this: `{ "id: " + Convert.ToString(id + orderid), "State: ACTIVE" };` to work properly. I've added this code to my answer for you.

Comment: Glad to be of help xD

Comment: A small last page of questions it's like in the example. from paypal how do I sort of like the "payment_definitions" coming into the plan?

Comment: Create a `PaymentDefinitions` class that maps to the same properties in the Json object (like you've done with the 'JsonPaypal' object). Then, in your `JsonPaypal` object, add a new propery called `PaymentDefinitions` of type `List<PaymentDefinitions>`. Wherever you're converting from (I use `Newtonsoft.Json`'s `ConvertToObject` method) will then translate it directly how you want it.

Comment: Thanks. i hope u will giv me +1 for my ask.